# Questions regarding the axioms of a topological space

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Given the topological space $T=(X,\tau)$ one of the axioms is:

"the union of any collection of sets in $\tau$ is in $\tau$"

I don't understand why this is an axiom. When is this not the case?

Comment: If $X$ has more than one point and $\tau$ is the collection of singleton subsets of $X$, for example.

Comment: Suppose that $X = \{1,2\}$, the set consisting of two elements. Then the collection $\tau := \{ \{1\},\{2\} \}$ of subsets in $X$ does not satisfy your "axiom".

Comment: Perhaps it might clarify things to restate that sentence with more care: "The union of any collection of elements of $\tau$ is an element of $\tau$" (knowing, of course, that each element of $\tau$ is a subset of $X$).